# How to get a a selected option from HTML <select> to a POST request in Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, post, sinatra, erb

How do I get the selected option from the HTML select option attribute to a POST request? So

```
<form method="post" action="new_choice/:pick_an_order/:pick_a_letter">

<select name="pick_an_order">
   <option>First</option>
   <option>Second</option>
   <option>Third</option>
 </select>

<select name="pick_a_letter">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
 </select>
```

If the user selects, as an example, the first option from each, being "First" and "A".  Right now I have:

```
post 'new_choice/:pick_an_order/:pick_a_letter' do
    pick_an_order = params[:pick_an_order]
    pick_a_letter = params[:pick_a_letter]

    @your_choice = YourChoice.new(pick_an_order, pick_a_letter)
    redirect '/to_a_page'

end
```

But for some reason it's not saving to @your_choice.  How do I get the selected attribute directly to the POST request so that it can be saved to the @your_choice object? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You must make a choice. Either you modify the value of the `action` attribute in your `form` with the help of Javascript, or you change the route of your resource to `post 'new_choice' do` and have the values sent as POST parameters.

I'll pick the second one because it seems more logical at the moment:

```
<form method="post" action="/new_choice">

<select name="pick_an_order">
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">Second</option>
  <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="pick_a_letter">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Please note that you must specify the `value` attribute for each `option`, that's the actual value sent (whatever text inside the tag is for the users). Then in Sinatra:

```
post '/new_choice' do
  pick_an_order = params[:pick_an_order]
  pick_a_letter = params[:pick_a_letter]

  @your_choice = YourChoice.new(pick_an_order, pick_a_letter)
  redirect '/to_a_page'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use javascript to submit the form because the code is so simple: 
`$(function() {
     $('#language').change(function() {
         this.form.submit();
     });
});`
Assign an id to the select tag, in this case it is `#language`.